# Does anybody have any experience with Hobo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

I'm thinking of adopting HOBO for quicker development of some Rails apps I want to develop on the side for myself.

Obviously there seems to be a certain learning curve to get the different concepts and specific coding practices of the gem and its dryml templates.

Also the documentation seems close to non-existent so I'm not sure I want to invest time in this direction but the intro screencast is very appealing to me.

Let me know of your experience of Rails + Hobo if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with Hobo for a while I've decided to keep developing in regular Rails.

Comment: I'm considering using Hobo.  I'm researching it and found your post, it's hard to know what might lurk around the bend.  What did you find?

Answer (score 6):

Having made a few web applications with Rails, and then currently working on another one I decided to try out Hobo, and I am impressed with the system. It requires extra learning, and it's hard for me to know how easy/difficult it would be to start out with Hobo if one knew nothing about Rails from beforehand. But for the next application, I'll definitively use Hobo again. Here are some of the key points that I like about it:

- Very well documented
- Produces clean and well-tagged HTML
  code, that makes work on CSS easier
- You get a lot for free when it comes
  to accounts and permissions
- You get a lot for free by models and
  interrelations being set up by
  default in a way that very much
  resembles what you want (in models as
  well as views)

The claims made by the developers, that Hobo makes for a more DRY approach, and takes the convention before configuration further, is very much the case as far as I have experienced it.

I would suggest starting out by following along the tutorials. They will give a fairly clear view of what Hobo is about, and wether this is of interest to you or not.

Answer (score 2):

I find Hobo in some ways DRYer than Rails and more accessible to n00bs.

Comment: Documentation is much better now, since there's "Rapid Rails with Hobo," a book authored by 3 people who've used Hobo quite extensively. I haven't read the full book (it's over 300 pages long!), but the sections I've read are very good.